# Register DLL in IIS 8.5 problems Global.asa

Tags: iis, dll, global.asa

I have one server with IIS 5.0 running an ASP application. I changed the ASP application from Windows Server 2003 to Windows Server 2012, so I've installed IIS 8.5 and I've activated the ASP extension. It's ok, but I have a problem.

I have one extension which is named Gestion.dll, When I try to access the URL, I found this error:

> This Object has a ProgID no valid.

I don't know how I can add the DLL extension to solve it. I have tried to add DLL with a module in the IIS 8.5 administrator, but it isn't running.

Comment: did you run "C:\Windows\System32\regsvr32 <youdll>" ? i suppose you have 32 bit DLL on 64 bit OS. i also suppose, that you already enabled 32-bit support in IIS

Comment: yes, I have a 64 bit OS. Windows Server 2012, I registered my DLL, REGSVR32 Gestion.dll and I enabled the 32 mode ASP in IIS 8.5. But doesn't work. The error is: The ActiveX can not create oUsuario Object.

Comment: Páginas Active Server error '00000000'

Error al crear objeto

?

Error al crear el objeto "oUsuario".

Error de Microsoft VBScript en tiempo de ejecución error '800a01ad'

El componente ActiveX no puede crear el objeto: 'oUsuario'

/vscript/globales.vbs, línea 58